# Python type hint pickable argument

Tags: python, pickle, type-hinting

I want to communicate to users of my code that some function requires a pickable object. Here is an example that abstracts from any project details:

```py
import pickle
from typing import Callable


def pickable():
    print("I am pickable!")


def get_non_pickable():
    # local functions are not pickable
    def not_pickable():
        print("I am NOT pickable!")

    return not_pickable


def pickle_func(func: Callable[[], None]):
    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(func, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


# fine:
pickle_func(pickable)

# not fine: should show in my editor that I am passing a non-pickable item
pickle_func(get_non_pickable())
```

Is it possible to type hint that the function argument `func` in the function `pickle_func` must be pickable? Ideally the existing type hint for the argument should be kept.

Comment: Being pickleble is not a type and neither a particular interface. It depends on the object and its attributes and sub-attributes which all may change at runtime. IMHO type annotations are not the right medium here. I suggest a less formal way to document it like in the doc string.

Comment: Based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable, this is statically analysable using existing static type checkers (if you're allowed to customise them), because type checkers require resolution of fully-qualified names of objects, and inner functions' fully-qualified names will usually contain non-identifiers. For example, a mypy plugin can lint unpicklable arguments to your `pickle_func` using [`get_function_signature_hook`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pickling saves the name ("identifier") of a function. Un-pickling requires re-importing the function by name. For that to work, the function needs to be defined at the top-level. Wrapping a function inside another one violates this requirement.

I'm not sure if there's a way to type-hint top-level functions.